# Problem in an Insert : values list are not matching column list

Tags: php, mysql, web

So basically, I have to retrieve the primary keys of two tables which are linked by a multiple association (if the name in the "joueur" table matches the name in the "match_rencontre" table, then i select their IDs. And then I have to insert these keys into the table "participer", to find out who are the players who participated

here is my database, i'm working on xampp, so if you wanna test it : http://www.filedropper.com/wszzzzcebasketsql

[image]

The error i get is : "Error : SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 "
I don't want to insert something into "note" and "titulaire" for the moment.

Thanks for your help

```
<?php
require('database.php');
global $db;
$req = $db->prepare("SELECT joueur.n_license, match_rencontre.id_match_rencontre FROM match_rencontre, joueur, participer WHERE  joueur.n_license = participer.n_license AND  participer.id_match_rencontre = match_rencontre.id_match_rencontre AND joueur.joue = match_rencontre.nom_equipe_adverse");

$req->execute();
while ($row = $req->fetch()) {
        $n_license = (int)$row['joueur.n_license'];
        $id_match_rencontre = (int)$row['match_rencontre.id_match_rencontre'];
    }
}

try {
    $query = "INSERT INTO participer(n_license, id_match_rencontre) VALUES ('$n_license','$id_match_rencontre')";
    $go=$db->prepare($query);
    $go->execute();
}   catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: `note` and `titulaire` field seem to be missing, might these be required fields? If you want to update an existing row's values you should have a look at [MySQL Update](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Also, why are you using a prepared statement for the `INSERT` without binding any parameters?

Comment: Yes i've tried to debug it and it's not working, thanks i will try that

Comment: **What** have you tried to debug the problem? Could you share the table structure in readable form such that others could reproduce the problem?

Comment: i've tried to add the rows that i didn't wanted to fill in the insert query with values ('?') I'm beginning in CS so i working on xammp, i've posted the link to download the db on sql.zip format